# Sending MIDI using MIDISendEventList() in C/C++

Tags: ios, c, midi, coremidi, ump

I've been working to migrate an older Core MIDI sending implementation to send MIDI 1.0 messages using Apple's newer UMP-aware MIDI Event List API methods.

I've figured out code that runs and *should* output MIDI clock messages, but when I send it with `MIDISendEventList(...)` I see nothing being output from my MIDI interface; there's also no error returned from that method to indicate what the problem is.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
const ByteCount clockMessageSize = 1;
const UInt32 clockMessage[clockMessageSize] = { (UInt32)0xF8 };    // MIDI clock tick 
const MIDITimeStamp timeStamp = mach_absolute_time();
MIDIEventList clockMessageEventList = {};
MIDIEventPacket* clockMessageEventListEndPacket = nullptr;

clockMessageEventListEndPacket = MIDIEventListInit(&clockMessageEventList, kMIDIProtocol_1_0);
clockMessageEventListEndPacket = MIDIEventListAdd(&clockMessageEventList, sizeof(MIDIEventList::packet), clockMessageEventListEndPacket, timeStamp, clockMessageSize, clockMessage);
                
for (NSUInteger endpointRefIndex = 0; endpointRefIndex < endPointRefsCount; ++endpointRefIndex) {
    MIDIObjectRef destinationEndpoint = endPointRefs[endpointRefIndex];
    OSStatus midiSendError = MIDISendEventList(outputPortRef, destinationEndpoint, &clockMessageEventList);
                    
    if (midiSendError != noErr) {
        printf("MIDISendEventList error: %i", (int)midiSendError);
    }
 }
```

Inspecting `clockMessageEventList.packet` after it has been configured but before it is sent shows:

```
(248, 0, 0, [... all zeros to index 63])
```

Does anyone know where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a bit of additional direction provided by https://stackoverflow.com/a/74248460/8653957 I managed to crack this.

For some reason, the word created for the MIDI clock message needs to be formatted slightly differently, with the first byte being `0x10`, and the *second* byte being the MIDI clock message:

```
const ByteCount clockMessageSize = 1;
const UInt32 clockMessage[clockMessageSize] = { 0x10000000 | ((UInt32)message << 16) };
const MIDITimeStamp timeStamp = mach_absolute_time();
MIDIEventList clockMessageEventList = {};
MIDIEventPacket* clockMessageEventListEndPacket = nullptr;

clockMessageEventListEndPacket = MIDIEventListInit(&clockMessageEventList, kMIDIProtocol_1_0);
clockMessageEventListEndPacket = MIDIEventListAdd(&clockMessageEventList, sizeof(MIDIEventList::packet), clockMessageEventListEndPacket, timeStamp, clockMessageSize, clockMessage);
```

If anyone know why this is, please post it! But here you go, MIDI clock via MIDIEventList.

Answer (score 3):

I don't have enough reputation to reply to the reply asking why the 0x10 fix is necessary, but the reason you need 0x10 is because the event list uses a "universal MIDI packet" format instead of the standard MIDI format.

This format needs a "message type" in the first two bytes - 0x10 is classified as "MIDI 1.0 - System Real Time and System Common Messages". MIDI 1.0 also supports 0x20 (channel voice messages, such as a note on) and 0x30 (data messages for SYSEX).

CoreMIDI also provides functions to generate these 32-bit values, e.g. MIDI1UPSystemCommon would take care of the 0x10 for you, avoiding the need to manually shift bits.